# NSIS installer fails to find existing files while compiling

Tags: installation, nsis

So I have been trying to build an installer for my game with NSIS. For the most part it works fine but just noticed that it seems to be skipping certain files for no reason. Or no reason I can figure out.

At first I was using this line to gather up all the files in the source folder:

```
File /r "${NSISDIR}\game\source\*.*"
```

However, I noticed that this didn't get everything. Granted it found all sub-folders and kept the hierarchy correct.  There didn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to what it skipped.  Then I tried listing all files and directories separately and found out why.  Example:

```
File "${NSISDIR}\OWTD-DE\source\pygame.math.pyd"
```

This produces the following error:

```
File: "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\game\source\pygame.math.pyd" -> no files found.
```

But that file exists, I can see it in the source folder.  This was the case for all missing files.  At first I thought it may be the two periods in the name, but various files have that naming convention and they are added fine. I cannot figure out how to get it to recognize these files.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you give us some more samples of file names that work and file names that don't work?

Comment: @RolandBär Hey there.  Here are the next three lines:              `File "${NSISDIR}\game\source\pygame.color.pyd"
  File "${NSISDIR}\game\source\pygame.constants.pyd"
  File "${NSISDIR}\game\source\pygame.display.pyd"`   They follow the same naming convention.  Also I built the list using ls > depends.txt  so that the spelling and list was complete when adding them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly enough, this process did not work very well on Windows Home 64-Bit but did on Windows Professional 64-Bit.  I'm not sure if this an issue with NSIS itself or what, but nothing was different between the two except the OS.  And there really isn't much difference between those two operating systems.  However, perhaps some configuration differences between the two was the real issue.

While marked solved, I'm not really sure what the actual issue and solution could be.

Answer (score 1):

`${NSISDIR}` is a define used to access the UI resources in the Contrib subfolder, you are not supposed to put your files there. Your source files should not be in Program Files, only installed files should be located there. Also, on 64-bit systems there are two Program Files folders and there are some compatibility hacks in Windows related to %ProgramFiles% so putting your source files there is not optimal. Just because **you** see that file there does not mean it is actually in Program Files, it could be [UAC Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756960.aspx)/VirtualStore tricking you...

Normally you would keep your .nsi somewhere in the same directory tree as the rest of your files so you can use relative paths but you can also use a define if you really want to:

```
!define MYSOURCE "c:\foo\bar"

...

Section
File /r "${MYSOURCE}\*.*"
SectionEnd
```

If it still misses some files I would suggest trying [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) so you can see the low-level details...

Comment: Tried moving the files out of Program Files to just C: base, still doesn't add those files particularly.  Also viewed the drive in Linux, via dual-boot, and it shows the files to be intact and with no hidden extensions.  Very odd problem.  I will try Process Monitor and !define